# Remove duplicate delegate from event

Tags: c#

I would like to remoe duplicate delegates from an event. So I have written the following code. It works fine. My application is a time critcal application. Is there any other optimized mechansim to achieve the same. Please help me

---

```
public void FireEvent()
{
    Dictionary<Delegate, Delegate> dic = new Dictionary<Delegate, Delegate>();

    Delegate[] m = this.Paused.GetInvocationList();
    foreach (Delegate d in m)
    {
        Delegate dout;
        if (dic.TryGetValue(d, out dout))
        {                    
            continue;
        } 
        else
        {
            dic.Add(d, d);
        }
        d.DynamicInvoke(new object[2] { this, null });
    }
}
```

Comment: Suppose someone actually *wants* a delegate to fire twice?

Comment: With the current architecture, it is not necessary to fire a delegate twice..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Problem with original approach

If this is really a time critical application, I would strongly advise changing your code.

1. You construct and populate a new `Dictionary<Delegate, Delegate>` on *every method call*. This is quite wasteful.
2. You use `DynamicInvoke`, which has slower performance than regular invocation to begin with.
3. You construct a new `object[]` to pass as a parameter to your `DynamicInvoke` call, again on *every* `FireEvent` call.

This is a bit of a corruption of the established mechanism for event handling.

### Suggestion for improved approach

Here's a much better solution, in my opinion: instead of having this `FireEvent` method which bends over backwards to ignore duplicate delegates that have been added, why not just prevent delegates from being attached to the event multiple times in the first place?

```
private HashSet<EventHandler> _pausedHandlers = new HashSet<EventHandler>();

public event EventHandler Paused
{
    add // will not add duplicates
    { _pausedHandlers.Add(value); }

    remove
    { _pausedHandlers.Remove(value); }
}
```

Then you can simply raise the event in the much more conventional, time-tested way, confident that no delegates have been attached to the event more than once.

```
protected void OnPaused()
{
    foreach (EventHandler handler in _pausedHandlers)
    {
        try
        {
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
        catch
        {
            // up to you what to do here
        }
    }
}
```

### Note on the concept of "duplicate delegates"

The comments to this answer have shed some light on the issue of delegate equality that I felt it would be beneficial to include in this answer. If you're interested, take a look at the following code example I wrote in an attempt to make this topic a little bit easier to understand.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Even though the code for FirstHandler and SecondHandler is the same,
        // they will not (nor should they) be considered equal for the purpose
        // of detecting duplicates.
        EventHandler handler1 = FirstHandler;
        EventHandler handler2 = SecondHandler;

        // Since handler2 and handler3 point to the same method, on the other
        // hand, they will (and ought to) be treated as equal.
        EventHandler handler3 = SecondHandler;

        // So this prints 'False'...
        Console.WriteLine(handler1.Equals(handler2));

        // ...and this prints 'True'.
        Console.WriteLine(handler2.Equals(handler3));

        // Now take a look at the code for SetAnonymousHandler below. The
        // method accepts an EventHandler by reference and compares it for
        // equality to a delegate pointing to an anoymous lambda method. If the
        // two are equal, it sets the EventHandler to this new delegate and 
        // returns true; otherwise it returns false.

        // This prints 'True', as handler1 is not equal to the delegate
        // declared within the SetAnonymousHandler method.
        Console.WriteLine(SetAnonymousHandler(ref handler1));

        // HOWEVER, now it prints 'False' for a simple reason: the delegate 
        // declared in SetAnonymousHandler points to an actual method. The fact
        // that it is an anonymous method simply means that the compiler
        // automatically generates a "proper" method for it in IL (to see what
        // I mean, read the comment at the bottom of this class). So now,
        // as with handler2 and handler3 above, handler1 and the delegate
        // declared in SetAnonymousHandler point to the same method and are
        // therefore equal; the method returns false.
        Console.WriteLine(SetAnonymousHandler(ref handler1));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void FirstHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Testing");
    }

    static void SecondHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Testing");
    }

    static bool SetAnonymousHandler(ref EventHandler handler)
    {
        EventHandler anonymous = (sender, e) => Console.WriteLine("Testing");

        if (!handler.Equals(anonymous))
        {
            handler = anonymous;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Note: When the above method is compiled, the C# compiler generates code
    // that would look something like this if translated back from IL to C#
    // (not exactly, but the point is just to illustrate that an anoymous
    // method, after compilation, is really just like a "proper"
    // -- i.e., non-anonymous -- method).

    //static bool SetAnonymousHandler(ref EventHandler handler)
    //{
    //    EventHandler anonymous = SetAnonymousHandler_Anonymous;

    //    if (handler.Equals(anonymous))
    //    {
    //        handler = anonymous;
    //        return true;
    //    }
    //    else
    //    {
    //        return false;
    //    }
    //}

    //static void SetAnonymousHandler_Anonymous(object sender, EventArgs e)
    //{
    //    Console.WriteLine("Testing");
    //}
}
```

Comment: +1. Would this work with anonymous methods / lambda-expressions?

Comment: @Ani: It would work for adding only. In any scenario where you are planning on adding *and removing* handlers to/from an event throughout the lifetime of an application, you must use either proper methods or persistent delegate objects (e.g., an `EventHandler` that is stored in a variable), the reason being that if you add a handler in one place and try to remove it in another using a lambda expression, the resulting code refers to two separately defined methods that have been automatically generated by the compiler.

Comment: @Dan Tao: Thanks. On that basis, why would it work for adding but not removing? If I did:
`myEvent+=(sender,args) => Console.WriteLine("Hello world");
myEvent+=(sender,args) => Console.WriteLine("Hello world");`, wouldn't the second delegate also be added?

Comment: Dan Tao.  Thanks for the reply. We use GetInvocationList. DynamicInvoke to handle exceptions thrown by the delegate. We have to execute remaining delegates even though one delegate throws an exception(for eg: due to remoting exception.). do you have any suggestion for this?

Comment: @Maanu: Sure -- you can always enumerate over the delegates in your collection manually. See my updated answer.

Comment: @Ani: Those are 2 different delegate instances. If it is in a method that is called twice, I suspect .NET caches the original, and on the subsequent method call, another 2 delegates wont be added again. I could be wrong on this  :)

Comment: @Dan Tao: Perhaps you want to add what I said to @Ani in your answer.

Comment: @Ani & @Dan Tao: I was incorrect :(  It will actually add more on subsequent method calls using the normal multicast delegate approach. Going to test your alternative now.

Comment: @Ani: Oh, I misunderstood your question! I thought you were asking, "Would this work," as in, "Will handlers be added/removed properly?" -- but you were actually referring to the handling of duplicates. You're right that anonymous methods that *do the same thing* may very well be added twice; but if you think about it, these aren't actually "duplicates" any more than two separate methods that just happen to contain the same code are duplicates. Anyway, the OP's original code wouldn't prevent duplicates of this sort either, so at least this isn't a step back.

Comment: @leppie: I think what I said to @Ani gets to the crux of this issue: if you have two anonymous methods, even if they contain exactly the same code, they really are still two separate methods, just as two proper (non-anonymous) methods with the same code are separate entities. The compiler must generate an instance of each in order not to break the functionality of a program, e.g., if the developer deliberately defined a method twice to get around a mechanism like the one I have suggested here for the OP.

Comment: @Ani & @Dan Tao: This does work as I expected originally with your alternative. :)

Comment: @Ani: The compiler behavior is fine and expected for lambda delegates. There are more corner cases to be explored here however.

Comment: @Ani, @leppie, and @Maanu: I've updated my answer with some code that should hopefully illustrate some of these issues that we have discussed in the course of these comments.